# Parsing custom keys in Json with Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I have written this code

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._, io.circe.generic.extras._
implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default
case class Company(name: String)
case class Quote(average: Double)
case class Stats(price: Double)
@ConfiguredJsonCodec case class Bulk(company: Company, @JsonKey("advanced-stats") stats: Stats, quote: Quote)
val input = """{"AAPL": {"company": {"name": "Apple"},"advanced-stats": {"price":10},"quote": {"average":10}}}"""
val parsed = decode[Map[String, Bulk]](input)
```

When I try to execute this inside of ammonite I get an error

```
cmd5.sc:1: macro annotation could not be expanded (you cannot use a macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
@ConfiguredJsonCodec case class Bulk(company: Company, @JsonKey("advanced-stats") stats: Stats, quote: Quote)
```

When I copy paste this code into a file and try to compile it then it gives compilation error

```
could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.codec.ConfiguredAsObjectCodec
```

Edit:: Thanks to the answer below the code started to work on ammonite. it still doesn't compile when I copy paste it into a Scala file. I googled and changed the code to

```
object DefaultValues {
  implicit val useDefaultValues = Configuration.default.withDefaults
}

import DefaultValues._
@ConfiguredJsonCodec
case class Bulk(
    company: Company,
    @JsonKey("advanced-stats") stats: Stats,
    quote: Quote
)
```

but it still says

```
could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.codec.ConfiguredAsObjectCodec[Bulk]
```

Comment: You can avoid the whole problem by using `\`advanced-stats\`` as the variable name instead of a custom codec.

Comment: You are right Ava. The road to hell is paved with the stones of "auto derivation" of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled macro annotations? Scala 2.13 require flag that you can enable in Ammonite with:

```
interp.configureCompiler(_.settings.YmacroAnnotations.value = true)
```

in earlier versions of Ammonite which used Scala 2.12 and earlier you have to use

```
// replace with Scala version appropriate for your Ammonite
//                                             \/
import $plugin.$ivy.`org.scalamacros:paradise_2.12.11:2.1.1`
```

Comment: Thanks this works in ammonite now. Do you know how I can make this work when the same code is copy pasted in a file? I do have `"-Ymacro-annotations"` in my build.sbt but  the line `implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default` doesn't compile

Comment: it says `could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.codec.ConfiguredAsObjectCodec[`

Comment: Scala 2 doesn't allow storing `val`s and `type`s as top-level definitions. They have to be defined in `class`, `trait` or `object` which can be sometimes worked around by putting things into `package object` (but there can be only one of them in project, so 2 modules cannot put things into `package object` with the same package name). Scala 3 has this apparently solved but for now I suggest putting `Configuration` into either package object with `private[your.package.name]` or into companion object that you need it for derivation (`object Bulk { implicit val configuration ... }`).